# Django form submit does not work

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have an EventForm form that i want to populate. I use event_form.attributes so I can customize the CSS. But nothing happens when I click submit - the action url is not called or anything.

EventForm:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Enter event name")
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=1024, help_text="Enter event description")
    date_str = forms.CharField(max_length=128,label="Date", help_text="Enter date in the format: DD/MM/YY")
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Enter event address")
    image = forms.ImageField(label="Event Image")
    volunteerLimit = forms.IntegerField(initial=10, label="Volunteer Limit")
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CATEGORY_SELECT, required=True)
    mininumAge = forms.IntegerField(initial=18, label="Minimum Age")
    closed = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(),initial=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        exclude = ( 'date', 'slug', 'volunteers', "organisation" )
```

base.html

```
        {% csrf_token %}
          <form id="event_form" method="post" action="/iVolunteer/add_event/">
          {% for hidden in event_form.hidden_fields %}
              {{ hidden }}
          {% endfor %}
                <div class="form-group">
                  {{ event_form.name.errors }}
                  {{ event_form.name.label_tag }}
                  {{ event_form.name|addclass:"form-control form-style"}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ event_form.description.errors }}
                    {{ event_form.description.label_tag }}
                    {{ event_form.description|addclass:"form-control form-style"}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ event_form.date_str.errors }}
                    {{ event_form.date_str.label_tag }}
                    {{ event_form.date_str|addclass:"form-control form-style"}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ event_form.address.errors }}
                    {{ event_form.address.label_tag }}
                    {{ event_form.address|addclass:"form-control form-style"}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ event_form.category.errors }}
                    {{ event_form.category.label_tag }}
                    {{ event_form.category|addclass:"form-control form-style"}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ event_form.mininumAge.errors }}
                    {{ event_form.mininumAge.label_tag }}
                    {{ event_form.mininumAge|addclass:"form-control form-style"}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ event_form.volunteerLimit.errors }}
                    {{ event_form.volunteerLimit.label_tag }}
                    {{ event_form.volunteerLimit|addclass:"form-control form-style"}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ event_form.image.errors }}
                    {{ event_form.image.label_tag }}
                    {{ event_form.image|addclass:"form-control form-style"}}
                </div>


            <div class="modal-footer">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-standard" name="submit" value="Create Event" data-dismiss="modal">
            </div>

            </form>
```

Any comment or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You will have an easier time using the [`attrs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) attribute of the widget constructor tehn doing it in the template.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not at `/iVolunteer/add_event/` try to put `action=""`. Put `{% csrf_token %}` inside the form too.